# Multiple for loop variable in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in VBA:

`For n = 1 To 15`

```
Cells(n, 8) = Application.Combin(2 * n, n)

next n
```

I want the n in the `cells(n,8)` to have an incerement 2, so the code skips a line after each entry.

Is it possible to have an other increment variable in this same loop that jumps 2 at once?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: after reading the comment: I think what is needed is a counter to count, 1,2,3,4,5,6...15, and another one to count 1,3,5,7...15

For that, here is what is need to be done:
basically, you want the first iterator to be a normal counter,
and the second iterator to be odd numbers only.

So here is a simply input output table

```
input           output
-----           -----
1                1
2                3
3                5
4                7
5                9
6                11
```

From the above, we can deduce the formula needed to convert the input into the desired output: `output = (input x 2) -1`

And so, we can re-write our for loop to be like so:

```
For n=1 to 15
    Cells(n,8) = Application.Combin(2*n-1,n)
Next
```

============= End of Edit =========================

Simply, use the keyword STEP in the for loop

```
For n = 1 To 15 STEP 2   'STEP can also be negative
                         'but you have to reverse the starting, and endin
                         'value of the iterator
```

The values for `n` will be: `1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 , 13, 15`

Alternatively, use a local variable inside the for loop for that purpose (in-case you want the loop to execute 15 times)

```
For n=1 to 15
    i = n + 1
    Cells(i,8) = Application.Combine(2*n,n)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the values for `n` to be  `1,3,5,..` only in the `cells()`. In the combin, I want them to be `1,2,3,4,5,`